# How to fix white screen issue in google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10

I've tried several solutions online and nothing works.
Disabled hardware accelerator and removed all chrome extensions.
...
I am on win 10 and my chrome version is 104.0.5112.81
[Google Chrome issue](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hnX1j5A8TpzdBG-eBxJVJ2_6W_AnOuvY/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you explain briefly what you tried?

Comment: I've disabled hardware acelerator and removed all chrome extensions.
And deleted all cookies and other site data

Comment: Can you try uninstall and install

Comment: I think attacking mallware. Can you do reinstall

Comment: I already reinstalled several times but still didn't work

Comment: Just tried on microsoft edge and same issue. So it's google search engine issue?

Comment: I've tried other browsers like opera, edge, brave and etc. All have same issues.
So I think it's related to my system or google search engine not browser

Comment: Virus attacked should be need to reboot your os

Comment: I've already rebooted my os many times

Comment: I've tried in Win10 VirtualBox and the issue does not happen. Could it be related to driver?